# ElasticSearch Mapping Issue - Nested to Non-Nested

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I am creating a mapping for data generated by a computer vision application. However, I am getting an error when I test pushing an example data message to ElasticSearch. I have read tons of forums where others have had this issue. Some have resolved their issue but I have tried everything I know to try. I actually think there may be a simple resolution but I am relatively new to Elastic 
Search.

The index and mapping are created successfully using:

```
PUT vision_events
{
  "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 5
    },
  "mappings" : {
        "properties": {
          "camera_id": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "hit_counts": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "intersection": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "label": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "locations": {
          "type" : "nested",
           "properties": {
            "coords" : {
                "type" : "float"
            },
            "location": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "street_segment": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "timestamp": {
              "type": "date"
            }
          }
        },
        "pole_id": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "timestamp": {
        "type":   "date"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Once completed, I move on to validating the mapping is correct. I push the following example data:

```
POST /vision_events/1?pretty=true
{
  "pole_id": "mlk-central-2",
  "camera_id": "mlk-central-cam-2",
  "intersection": true,
  "id": "644d1c06-4c60-4ed8-93b4-1aa79b87a622",
  "label": "car",
  "timestamp": 1586838108683,
  "locations": [
    {
      "timestamp": 1586838109448,
      "coords": 1626.3220383482665,
      "street_segment": "None"
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 1586838109832,
      "coords":  1623.3129222859882,
      "street_segment": "None"
    }
  ],
  "hit_counts": 2
}
```

This produces the following error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "object mapping [locations] can't be changed from nested to non-nested"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "object mapping [locations] can't be changed from nested to non-nested"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

The locations field is a list of "objects" which contain the fields: coords, location, street_segment and timestamp. Messages have varying length of locations. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post request should be PUT /vision_events/_doc/1 --> note _doc

Comment: This was successful. This exact message is sent via a Kafka ES Connector still results in the same issue. Maybe I need to repost with information on the entire pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Put the unchanged mapping:

```
PUT vision_events
{"settings":{"number_of_shards":5},"mappings":{"properties":{"camera_id":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"hit_counts":{"type":"long"},"id":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"intersection":{"type":"boolean"},"label":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"locations":{"type":"nested","properties":{"coords":{"type":"float"},"location":{"type":"text"},"street_segment":{"type":"text"},"timestamp":{"type":"date"}}},"pole_id":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"timestamp":{"type":"date"}}}}
```

Insert a single doc in accordance w/ the POST structure [from the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#docs-index-api-request):

```
POST /vision_events/_doc/1?pretty=true
{
  "pole_id": "mlk-central-2",
  "camera_id": "mlk-central-cam-2",
  "intersection": true,
  "id": "644d1c06-4c60-4ed8-93b4-1aa79b87a622",
  "label": "car",
  "timestamp": 1586838108683,
  "locations": [
    {
      "timestamp": 1586838109448,
      "coords": 1626.3220383482665,
      "street_segment": "None"
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 1586838109832,
      "coords": 1623.3129222859882,
      "street_segment": "None"
    }
  ],
  "hit_counts": 2
}
```